# Running Python zipapp as base64?

Tags: python, zip, base64, ascii

I recently discovered the magic of `__main__.py` when trying to run the same script on thousands of Linux servers, probably no two of which have exactly the same config. One of the limitations of our archaic system automation tool is that it only accepts ASCII text as the commands to run.

I somewhat snarkily suggested that we just pretend it was 1989 again and use Shell Archive (shar) files to distribute our Python ZIPs for execution.

Other options include a perl or python text-only script with embedded code to self-extract and run the "real" binary from an embedded base64 block.

The best option would be if there were a way to have the python interpreter directly execute a base64 or other ASCII-only encoded ZIP like it does with the binary ZIPs.

**Is running an ASCII-only zipapp bundle possible with Python**? What setup is needed to make that work? (Just trying to run a base64 encoded file with Python gives the not-entirely-unexpected "syntax error")